# AngularJS 2.0 - How to test the application?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine

I'm building an AngularJS app (using ES6) that is as much AngularJS 2.0 as possible, so I won't have lots of work with migration.

As you know there won't be controllers as we know them in <=v1.4

Example code of one of my directives

```
class LoginSidebar {

    constructor() {

    }

    someMethod(){
    }   
}

LoginSidebar.$inject = [];

export default function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'tpl/path/to/loginSidebar.tpl.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: LoginSidebar,
        controllerAs: 'loginSidebarCtrl'
    };
};
```

This is what my app.js looks like

```
import loginSidebar from "./js/component/loginSidebar/LoginSidebar.js";

angular.module('myModule', [
    'ngNewRouter',
    'ngAnimate'
])

    .directive("loginSidebar", loginSidebar);
```

As you can see I have no `.controller()` in there, so how am I supposed to test the methods inside the class ?

PS. 
I have tried using Karma-Jasmine, but I have to test the whole directive and if I do so, I get the error I wrote here: [AngularJS & Karma-Jasmine - How to ignore templateUrl to avoid "Unexpected request: GET .../.html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995436/angularjs-karma-jasmine-how-to-ignore-templateurl-to-avoid-unexpected-reque)

Answer (score 0):

You can define controller with global name, and then reference it in directive:

```
//LoginSidebarController.js
class LoginSidebarController {
  // controller code here
}

export default LoginSidebarController

//LoginSidebarDirective.js
export default function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'tpl/path/to/loginSidebar.tpl.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: 'LoginSidebarController',
        controllerAs: 'loginSidebarCtrl'
    };
};

//app.js
import loginSidebarDirective from "./js/component/loginSidebar/LoginSidebarDirective.js";
import LoginSidebarController from "./js/component/loginSidebar/LoginSidebarController.js";

angular.module('myModule', [])
     .directive('loginSidebar', loginSidebarDirective)
     .controller('LoginSidebarController', LoginSidebarController)
```

Then you can require controller as other usual controller to test it independently from directive.

As the second way you can get access to controller via `angular.element().controller('loginSidebar')` method. Something like this:

```
var testElm = angular.element('<login-sidebar />');
$compile(testElm);
testElm.controller('loginSidebar')
```